# AWS Error: Error during Url validation; check URL and try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]I'm trying to deploy a test site to AWS via the toolkit for visual studio, and I'm getting a strange error at the environment selection page.  Google searches are yielding no real information on it.

The error appears when I try to validate the url choice.  It says, "Error during URL validation; check URL and try again."  I have changed the url to everything I can think of, with no luck.  When I hit next, no matter what the URL is, a message box appears informing me that the URL is not available.  Is there a way around this error?

Comment: The reason usually is because url is already taken by somebody... Have you tried to put something totally random?

Comment: Yes; that is why it is strange...no matter what I put in, it yields the same error

Comment: Make sure the URL also conforms to the rules set by AWS, like 4 to 23 characters, not taken, etc. Though it's most likely just VS.

Comment: reinstalled the toolkit; still the same error

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AWS.

First, go to AWS, click on Services -> IAM, at the top left. Follow the instructions at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_SettingUpUser.html 
to create an IAM user. This will create an alias, essentially, for your account. You will need the access key and secret key, so download the file when prompted.

Second, while in the IAM management portal, click on Policies, on the left. You can check up to two options, and use them to create a Policy. Choose EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk, full access for each. You should do this with the IAM user you created, though I believe that you can use your main account.

Finally, you'll need to assign that profile to your web project. In the AWS Explorer, click on the New Account Profile at the top. You'll be prompted to enter some information; here is where you will need those keys. Once that is all done, try the Publish to AWS wizard, again.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond below; this answer was too long for a reply. What may be happening, is that the profile you are using does not have permission to create the container for your web application. This has nothing to do with URL availability; checking that URL is just the first time that the wizard checks with AWS. I got the same error, once upon a time.

Comment: Haha, it worked! :)  Been struggling against this for a few days... Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! That one too me a few days, as well. I had to run a manual deployment, to get a useful error message.

Comment: @dylanthelion Under the IAM Management Portal policies, I'm not seeing "EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk".  The only one similar is:  "AWSElasticBeanstalkCustomPlatformforEC2Role".  Should I choose this option?  Thanks.

Comment: AmazonEC2FullAccess and AmazonElasticBeanstalkFullAccess are the fully qualified names.

Comment: I cannot select the two, just one. You need to search for 'AmazonElasticBeanstalkFullAccess ' otherwise it will not show up in the list. Regardless, selecting two doesnt work for me.

Creating a new policy by clicking "Create policy" is messy, to say the least...

Comment: How does the IAM users relate? I havent specifiec in the AWS Toolkit anything regarding the IAM users, I think? I have a Access Code and Secret Access Code, but I think thats the "root" credentials, but its hard to tell?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't done AWS hosting in about 2 years, but it used to be either 2 or 3 permissions per Policy. The IAM user is an optional (but important) security option. If you're the only developer on the project, you can just use your main user account. Think of it as an admin account. But if you want to bring in Sue to help with SSL, or your build pipeline, or whatever, and you don't want to give her full access to everything, you create an IAM User with the necessary permissions to do what Sue needs, and no more.

Answer (score 12):

**Services** -> **IAM** -> **Users** -> Click on your user -> **Permissions** section -> **Attach Policy** -> Add **AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess** policy.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. It turned out that what was happening was that my `Secret Access Key` on my profile was missing a character. Fixing this made everything else run smoothly.

Comment: I made a new profile and used the copy from csv option instead of copy pasting myself and that profile worked. So I suspect I had a typo too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given your profile permission to Create an EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Comment: No; is that something I need to do? On AWS or VS?

Answer (score 0):

So, for me I tried everything mentioned here and it still wasn't working. After stepping away for 2 hours I tried it again... and it worked!!

Looks like there was a sync delay of some sort in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a connection problem. Before publishing check if the aws explorer in VS is showing the resources. If it doesn't then the connectivity needs to be checked.