# Error during url validation; check url and try again - publish to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy .Net website to `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`. 
For this:

1. Downloaded `AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio`
2. In `visual studio` from `solution explorer` right click on my project and selected `Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk`.
3. Then I entered credentials for `IAM` user that I downloaded from `credentials.csv` file.
   [image: IAM user credentials]
4. On next step, I received error on checking availability:

> Error during url validation; check url and try again

[image]

and if I click next then receive error in popup:

> CNAME dealkar-prod is unavailable

What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I'm still trying to figure out whats wrong.
This is the [link](http://sample-env.sxrx63ymqa.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/) of website that I created on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stack question that has some good suggestions to try:

[AWS Error: Error during Url validation; check URL and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462721/aws-error-error-during-url-validation-check-url-and-try-again/44532421#44532421)